# Android: How to run another program from my program and send argument to it

Tags: android

I'm writing a small program, it can show and manager all files and folder in the android mobile. Now I get a problem need to help, when I click to a file icon, example a audio, i want the audio player can run and play it. Who can help me

Comment: can not understand?..make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using intent you can invoke another application for example

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, NewClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

For more information refer following link
[link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to launch other programs.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will learn about it. Thanks for your help.